# Spaces with function definition in G. Kempf, Algebraic Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

I have started reading G. Kempf's Algebraic Varieties, and on first page they define a space with functions to be a topological space with a $k$-algebra of $k$-valued regular functions assigned to each open set. Then they define a regular function $f$ to be locally regular and that $1/f$ be regular on the open set $D(f) = \{x \in X | f(x) \neq 0\} $.  My question is why does it mean that the sum of two regular functions will also be regular, for example?

Comment: By definition the set of regular functions over a fixed open subset is equipped with a $\Bbbk$-algebra structure, so their sum defines a regular function.

Comment: I see. So it is so by definition, and not by a consequence of these properties of being locally regular or invertible on an appropriate domain. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just so this question has an answer, I copy my comment.

By definition the set of regular functions over a fixed open subset is equipped with a $\Bbbk$-algebra structure, so their sum defines a regular function.

---

An an aside, I think a modern sheaf-theoretic perspective on "spaces with functions" might be helpful. The structure of a 'space with $\Bbbk$-valued regular functions' on a topological space $X$ is precisely a subsheaf $\mathcal O_X$ of the sheaf of set-functions $f:X\to \Bbbk$ which has the following pair of *properties*. First, $f\in \mathcal O_X(U)\implies D_f\subset U$ is open where $D_f$ is the set of point on which $f$ is nonzero. Second, $f\in \mathcal O_X(U)\implies \frac 1f\in \mathcal O_X (D_f)$.

In my view, this characterization is more convenient for developing the theory of varieties, and also for relating it to the theory of schemes.

Comment: This is one of the properties G. Kempf's book requires of regular functions to have. The other one is that they are locally regular. And also that for each open set, the set of regular functions is a k-algebra.

Comment: One of the questions I have been having is how to relate this geometric structure to the algebra. And I think that's the content of the first few chapters. I have never seen algebraic geometry, but I have seen some basic stuff about how zero set of an ideal is defined to be an affine variety in algebra classes, and I still don't know how these two notions are connected.

Comment: @student I definitely cannot answer in a comment box, but roughly, the correspondence is this: given a space (geometry) you consider the regular functions on it (algebra), and given a family of polynomials (more generally - a commutative ring), you consider the space of solutions. Unrelated note - consider accepting answers to your questions!